# Can podaffinity schedule two pods to run on the same node?

Tags: kubernetes

Both pods are scheduled on same node with podaffinity, each pod on a different namespace. Once I try to deploy both of them on same namespace, podaffinity fails, and one one pod is running while the other one remains pending with podaffinity error.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your yaml config? 

It sounds like the pods might have a selector or label conflict (separating the namespaces would allow that conflict to be avoided, hence allowing them to run)

Comment: I will once I will be in front of my laptop. In the meantime, both of pods have same label and same podaffinity (which matches to the label as defined by podaffinity). Thus, with different namespace they are scheduled on same node. I believe that if they had different labels or podaffinity, it would not have been working. Is there a requirement to have two namespaces for podaffinity to work?

Comment: labels:
    app: myApp
    mykey: hac-xSQVQpWApJ
  name: <pod-name>
  namespace: source-ns
  resourceVersion: "613433"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/source-ns/pods/<pod-name>
  uid: 05b243f2-89a2-11e8-ad28-ce551f5cbbc6
spec:
  affinity:
    podAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: mykey
            operator: In
            values:
            - hac-xSQVQpWApJ
        topologyKey: hac

Comment: Maybe I should be more generic - could you please show me an example of how to use pod-affinity to schedule two pods on the same node? Do I have to label the node as well? is this the topologyKey for? is it a must? do both pods have to include the pod-affinity, or it's sufficient to label one pod and have the pod affinity only in the second pod with label selector matching the first pod's label? if you could show me how both pods should look like, that oudle be great. THanks!

Comment: found the problem. The tolpologyKey  value was not labeled on the node. Is there a way to schedule two pods on same node without labeling the node, either by user or hardcoded?

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, I suspect that you have a label collision that is only apparent when you try to run the pods in the same namespace.

Take a look at your [`nodeSelectorTerms`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) and `matchExpressions`

[From the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity):

> If you specify multiple matchExpressions associated with nodeSelectorTerms, then the pod can be scheduled onto a node only if all matchExpressions can be satisfied.

Comment: The purpose of podaffinity (as I see it) is the option of Not labeling the node.